# Accessing Static variables in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

Cakephp V2.6

In my current project I'm trying to lever some object oriented functionality. In my model, modelX i have created a custom find method to retrieve results in a specific way. I then return this array to the controller and serve it up to the view.

I'm implementing an excel plugin to export data, and the data in question is the same that's rendered to the view.
In my custom find, I assign the results to a static variable in my model before I return the results to the controller. 
When I click on my export button, I want to use the controller to call a modelX method to return this static array that can be passed to my plugin to export the data. However, I cannot seem to do it. I've tried declaring a static variable in the class, and it doesn't work. I've tried calling `global` on the variable within the method its assigned, but it doesn't work. The only way I've found around this so far is to write the variable to the session, which I can then access from anywhere at any time. While this does work, I think it to be inefficent. I don't think its a good idea to write a large array to the session every time a view is rendered because its not always going to be needed.

Is there a way in cake to assign data to a variable in a model that's available outside of an object instance so I can do this?

Comment: Why do you want to assign this value to the Model. Does it relate to model? Would be better if you showed some code here. It's not necessary to to be tight to the default file structure. You can create any files and directories you need. And the classes inside these files. And you can implement inside these classes any logix you need, including setter/getter.

Comment: Yes, relates to the model. I want to export from multiple models as and when, and I was looking to reference them via Model.variable from the superclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MyModel:

```
public static $x = array('a' => 'b');
```

In a controller:

```
$y = MyModel::$x;
```

Quote from php [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

> Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be
>   initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed.
>   So while you may initialize a static property to an integer or array
>   (for instance), you may not initialize it to another variable, to a
>   function return value, or to an object.

Use static methods when you need to execute some expressions before you return static array. In the model:

```
public static function getX() {
    $a = array('a' => 'b');
    $b = array('c' => 'd');
    return array_merge($a, $b);
}
```

In the controller:

```
$y = MyModel::getX();
```